# how to only select false statements in java

Tags: boolean, matching

I'm in a bit of a pickle and need some help. What I'm doing is some thing like:

```
 boolean[] turn1 = {false, false, false, false, false, false};
 boolean[] turn2 = {false, false, false, false, false, false};
```

I'm trying to make something like if I could make a pair from turn1 and turn2 true, how could I make it so that you could only choose those that are false? I am sorry beforehand if this seems a bit vague but I will answer any question if asked.

edit:ok ill try to specify. I'm trying to make matching pairs. I suppose it could be anything as long as they have the same word. I'm making a memory game. What I want is that when I choose a matching pair, they could never be selected again. So I figured that in order to do that is to make the matching pair true so I could limit myself from choosing those that are false.

Comment: I don't get what you mean here.

Comment: Yes, very vague.  What are you selecting/choosing, and how?

Comment: okay i guess lets just say fruits. So if there was something like String fruit1 = {apple, orange, banana, grape, pear} and the second one would be just like that but randomized.

Comment: How about creating another array of boolean with the same length as your arrays? Initialize all elements to false and make it true when selected. If a 'true' location is selected, give an error

Answer (score 0):

When approaching problems like this, it sometimes helps to think about how you'd do it in real life, without a computer. If I was playing a game of Memory with a child, we wouldn't use a separate piece of paper to track true/false marks of which cards had been selected and matched. We'd just remove the cards from the table.

So instead of using an array - which is fixed in size - use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which lets you access elements like an array, but also remove them, like a list.

Your initial set up is then something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> turn1 = new ArrayList<String>();
turn1.add("Orange");
turn1.add("Apple");
turn1.add("Banana");
turn1.add("Pear");
```

and similarly for `turn2`. When you've found a match, remove the items from each list:

```
turn1.remove(selection1);
turn2.remove(selection2);
```

Then you can simply continue until your list is empty (literally, `turn1.isEmpty()`)).